# How to call information from viewmodel inside of a setOnClickListener

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm trying to call the info from my viewmodel when there's an error and the user clicks a button to reload the info. The thing is, I cannot call it the way I have on success since the "it" on the setOnClickListener is not the same one as the viewmodel's data and it keeps crashing. How would I achieve this?

This is the part I'm talking about:

```
homeViewModel.newsResult.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            when (it.status) {
                Resource.Status.LOADING -> {
                }
                Resource.Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    newsAdapter = it.data?.let { it1 -> NewsAdapter(it1) }!!
                    binding.rvNews.adapter = newsAdapter
                }
                Resource.Status.ERROR -> {
                    binding.newsError.tvError.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.newsError.btnRetry.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.tvNewsTitle.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                    binding.newsError.btnRetry.setOnClickListener {
                        // i'd need to reload the recycler view here the same way as on success but that doesn't work here
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to put something into the reyclerview on error, but rather call the same function you first used to retrieve data in the ViewModel. Then the ViewModel will update its `newsResult` livedata, which you're already observing here, so there's nothing else you need to do. This is all assuming you are doing things correctly in the ViewModel.

Comment: @Tenfour04 okay but how do I set that up on click ? the design i was given indicates the part should reload when the user clicks the button

Comment: Just call it inside the click listener. It doesn't matter if you set the click listener directly in `onCreate()`/`onViewCreated()`, or inside the observer when you make it visible like you're doing now.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thank you, that makes sense and actually works.

Answer (score 0):

If the request returned ERROR you should send the request again in ERROR state. Not update the adapter. So you should call the request function of ViewModel inside ERROR.

Comment: you mean call the observers again?